# When is it possible to play the Salmon Run on online mode?

Tags: splatoon-2

I recently started playing splatoon 2 and from my research discovered that some itens can only be gotten by playing the Salmon Runs.

Unfortunetly I do not have any local friends to play with.
[This article on Inkipedia](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Salmon_Run) says it is open for online plays during certain time slots but doesn't specify when.

So, the actual question, when is it possible to play the Salmon Run online? Are there any periodic time slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salmon Run can be played online but only at certain times.

When in the plaza, bring up the menu, go to 'Stages' and choose 'Salmon Run'. It should tell you when Salmon Run is available online. If you can't play with friends, you will be put into a group with three other online players. As for the regularity, I believe it's usually once every two days for 24 hours at a time, but that might vary.

If you have the Nintendo Switch mobile app, the SplatNet service will also have notices on when Salmon Run is running.

Also, if a Salmon Run is available at the moment you first start the game, Pearl and Marina will mention their Grizzco sponsors during the announcements.

Comment: Thanks you! I Will probably ger the Nintendo Switch app to be noticed about it